# Git Diff, how can I get added lines?

Tags: git

I have some sql files in my project:

The content of one file in the last version is:

```
line1...
line2...
line3...
```

The same file in my current commit has:

```
line1...
line2...
line3...
line4...
line5...
```

I want a git command to get all the new lines from all ".sql" files.

I was trying with:

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD *.sql

diff --git a/patch.sql b/patch.sql
index e654124..c5692e4 100644
--- a/patch.sql
+++ b/patch.sql
@@ -4,3 +4,7 @@ line2
line1...
line2...
line3...
+line4...
+line5...
```

That's fine, but i just want:

```
line4...
line5...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pipe it to grep:

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD -- *.sql | grep "^+[a-Z0-9]"
```

You need to extra regex to avoid matching `+++ b/patch.sql`

Comment: @JaimeRivera Pipe to sed. Something like (untested): `sed -e 's/^+//g'`